# HTTPS page displays wrong

Tags: css, https, styles

I have a page that displays correctly in HTTP, but when I open it in HTTPS it seams that some CSS classes do not load propoerly.

Here it is: http://application.ninono.ca/application_iframe.php
and https://application.ninono.ca/application_iframe.php

Funny thing is that 80% of people will see no difference.

If anybody could shed some light on this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: here is what it lookls like on my PC: http://imgur.com/HCJewjS

Comment: Is the CSS file served through HTTPS?

Comment: Also , try changing http:// to https:// manually in the URL of theme stylesheet

Answer (score 1):

**Your browser is probably blocking un-secure content**

Some versions of recent browsers (**FireFox/Chrome**) will reject `HTTP` content when the page is served over `HTTPS`. This is to prevent insecure content being served alongside secure content.

So if you visit the homepage in Magento and specify `https://` in the URL, all the linked resources within the page source will still be `http://` - and the browser may reject loading that content to preserve security.

But if you've loaded the page once before, there's a good chance that some CSS/JS/Images may well already be in the browser cache, mitigating the requirement to fetch the resource remotely.

This can give the impression that it works on some machines and not on others. Where in reality - its not really working for anyone, its just that some users benefit from their historical browser cache.

Self-signed certificates can also produce this exact behaviour.

Comment: Thank you,
I came across another solution here on stackoverflow, which is to remove protocol reference at all from URL, like so: //yoursite.com/style/style.css